# How to split a string with multiple separators followed or not by whitespaces (mixed)?

Tags: php, split, whitespace

I'm looking for something that acts just like explode but using more than one string separator, i.e.

```
+ - (
```

could all be separators.

For example, after "exploding" the following string:

```
$string = 'We are 3+4-8 - (the + champions'
```

I should get this as $string[0]:

```
['We are 3+4-8']
```

Is there any function that acts that way?

Comment: you want to consider separator precisely what chars? And spaces?

Comment: You should try to better word your questions, you should get better and faster answers if you do a good job on describing your problem.

Comment: Use one of the answers from below and just access to the firs element in the resulting array, like $result[0]

Comment: @albertein i thought to have done, maybe Keoki didn't agree with me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = 'We are - (the + champions';
$words = preg_split('@[\W]+@', $string)
```

With this you obtain [We, are, the, champions]

```
$string = 'We are - (the + champions';
$words = preg_split('/[\+\-\(]/', $string)
```

With this you preserve whitespaces obtaining ['We are', ' ', 'the', 'champions']; it would be necessary a trim.

```
 $string = 'We are 3+4-8 - (the + champions';
 $words = preg_split('/[\+\-] |[\(]/', $string)
```

With this, finally, you obtain ['We are 3+4+8', 'the', 'champions']. Trim is not necessary in this case.

Comment: no, 'we are' has to be the first split of the string, i don't need a single word into the first array but every word before the separator.

Comment: changed like i imagine you wants

Comment: + and - are anticipated and followed by spaces... instead for '(' space is not relevant 'cause i have to split in any case

Answer (score 2):

Use [`preg_split()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with a character class.

```
$chars = '+-(';
$regexp = '/[' . preg_quote($chars, '/') . ']/';
$parts = preg_split($regexp, $string);
```

Forgot to add that if you're trying to **parse** expressions such as search queries, `preg_split()` won't cut it and you'll need a full fledged parser. I think there must be one in the Zend Framework.

Answer (score 1):

This will split your string by either `-`, `+`, or `(`

```
$result = preg_split(/[ \- ]|[ \+ ]|[(]/im, $string);
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $match){ 
  $result[$i] = trim($match);
}
```

Comment: You've got pattern mixed up with string...also, it doesn't return the same array given in the poster's example, it returns the same thing as explode, except with extra empty elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'We are - (the + champions';

$split = preg_split('/[\-,\(,\+]/', $string);
```

Comment: wait... 'e-p1' in this case - is not a separator. How to change?

Comment: `$string = 'We are 3-4+8 - (the + champions';` i need We are 3-4+8 'cause in this case - and + are not separators

Comment: `$split = preg_split('/[\(]/', $string);`

Comment: no, try to explain better: + and - ARE separators. Ok? Only when they are attached to other characters they are NOT separators. When they are anticipated and followed by spaces always ARE separators... Ok? :)

Comment: If you match it for " + " and " - " it will get rid of the white space in the results. The only way I can think of to get around this would be to do a str_replace() to something that couldn't possibly be in the string, then preg_split it matching for the "(", then str_replace back, then match for "+" and "-" and somehow combine the resultant arrays.

Edit: Another thing you could do if you need the white space would be to simply add it to everything.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = 'We are 3+4-8 - (the + champions';
$res = preg_split('/\s+[+(-]\s+/', $str);
print_r($res);
```

**output:**

```
[0] => We are 3+4-8
[1] => (the
[2] => champions
```